# Como registrar campos a una tabla c# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una ventana donde pongo un comentario y al momento de enviar los comentarios a una tabla que tengo me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese registro lo puse manualmente desde SQL Server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la parte del controlador tengo una funcion donde en el view la llamo desde formData.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Plantillas(Plantillas plantillas)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Plantillas.Add(plantillas);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    var msg = db.Plantillas.Where(x => x.PlantillaId == plantillas.PlantillaId);
                    string ComentarioPlant = db.Plantillas.Where(x => x.Comentario == plantillas.Comentario).ToString();

                    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "La plantilla ha sido registrada. "}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error al registrar la plantilla. "}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error al registrar la plantilla. " }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Qué error es el que estas recibiendo?

Comment: En la variable de plantillas el dato que recojo del view , me aparece como null pero si me registra en la tabla